# Generic Jolt Spec for Multiple Input JSON - Multiple Inputs

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I m having difficulty in writing a jolt spec for different JSON inputs. I need to get a generic jolt spec so that i get a flattened json.

Input 1 : We have a materialMovements array

```
{
  "id": "xxxxx",

  },
  "status": {
    "deliveryComplete": "xxxxx",

    ],
    "overallStatusDetail": "xxxxx",
    "overallStatus": "xxxxx"
  },
  "quantity": {
    "target": {
      "amount": "xxxxx",
      "baseUoM": "xxxxx",
      "ISOBaseUoM": "xxxxx"
    }
  },
  "dates": {
    "plannedFinishDate": "xxxxx",
    "plannedStartDate": "xxxxx",
    "actualFinishDate": "xxxxx"
  },
  "consumptionFlag": xxxxx,
  "billOfMaterials": "xxxxx",
  "deletionIndicator": "",
  "routingNumber": "xxxxx",
  "mainWorkCenter": "xxxxx",
  "orderRecipe": "xxxxx",
  "item": {
    "number": "xxxxx",
    "product": {
      "id": "xxxxx",
      "number": "xxxxx",
      "description": "xxxxx",
      "baseUoM": "xxxxx",
      "ISOBaseUoM": "xxxxx"
    },
    "goodsReceipt": {
      "amount": "xxxxx",
      "baseUoM": "xxxxx",
      "ISOBaseUoM": "xxxxx"
    },
    "storageLocation": {
      "code": "xxxxx",
      "description": "xxxxx"
    }
  },
  "reservation": {
    "id": "xxxxx",
    "number": "xxxxx",
    
  },
  "materialMovements": [
    {
      "id": "xxxxx",
      "number": "xxxxx",
      "postingDate": "xxxxx",
      "items": [
        {
          "number": "xxxxx",
          
          },
          "product": {
            "id": "xxxxx",

          }
          
        }
      ]
    }
    }
  ],
  "sourceSystem": "NA"
}
```

Input 2 : We dont have a materialmovements array

```
{
  "id": "xxxxx",

  },
  "status": {
    "deliveryComplete": "xxxxx",

    ],
    "overallStatusDetail": "xxxxx",
    "overallStatus": "xxxxx"
  },
  "quantity": {
    "target": {
      "amount": "xxxxx",
      "baseUoM": "xxxxx",
      "ISOBaseUoM": "xxxxx"
    }
  },
  "dates": {
    "plannedFinishDate": "xxxxx",
    "plannedStartDate": "xxxxx",
    "actualFinishDate": "xxxxx"
  },
  "consumptionFlag": xxxxx,
  "billOfMaterials": "xxxxx",
  "deletionIndicator": "",
  "routingNumber": "xxxxx",
  "mainWorkCenter": "xxxxx",
  "orderRecipe": "xxxxx",
  "item": {
    "number": "xxxxx",
    "product": {
      "id": "xxxxx",
      "number": "xxxxx",
      "description": "xxxxx",
      "baseUoM": "xxxxx",
      "ISOBaseUoM": "xxxxx"
    },
    "goodsReceipt": {
      "amount": "xxxxx",
      "baseUoM": "xxxxx",
      "ISOBaseUoM": "xxxxx"
    },
    "storageLocation": {
      "code": "xxxxx",
      "description": "xxxxx"
    }
  },
  "reservation": {
    "id": "xxxxx",
    "number": "xxxxx",
    
  },
  "sourceSystem": "NA"
}
```

I hv used the joltspec for the Input 1 which is working fine, i need it to work for the input 2 also

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "materialMovements": {
        "*": {
          "@(2,sourceSystem)": "[&1].SourceSystem",
          "@(2,number)": "[&1].ProcessOrderNumber",
          "@(2,item.number)": "[&1].ProcessOrderLineNumber",
          "@(2,item.product.number)": "[&1].MaterialToBeProduced",
          "@(2,item.storageLocation.code)": "[&1].StorageLocation",
          "@(2,item.goodsReceipt.amount)": "[&1].GoodsReceiptQuantity",
          "@(2,locationIdentifier.id)": "[&1].Plant",
          "@(2,billOfMaterials)": "[&1].BillOfMaterials",
          "@(2,creationDate)": "[&1].CreationDate",
          "@(2,dates.plannedFinishDate)": "[&1].PlannedFinishDate",
          "@(2,dates.plannedStartDate)": "[&1].plannedStartDate",
          "@(2,actualFinishDate)": "[&1].ActualFinishDate",
          "@(2,deletionIndicator)": "[&1].DeletionIndicator",
          "@(2,quantity.target.amount)": "[&1].OrderQuantity",
          "@(2,quantity.target.baseUoM)": "[&1].UOM",
          "@(2,quantity.confirmed.amount)": "[&1].ConfirmedQuantity",
          "@(2,mainWorkCenter)": "[&1].MainWorkCenter",
          "@(2,orderRecipe)": "[&1].OrderRecipe",
          "@(2,Message Timestamp)": "[&1].LastModifiedOn",
          "@(2,status.overallStatusDetail)": "[&1].StatusDetail",
          "@(2,status.overallStatus)": "[&1].Status",
          "postingDate": "[&1].ActualDeliveryDate"
        }
      }
    }
  }
    ]
```

Comment: merge two json files into one and then apply jolt

Comment: merging two json files means, each time different kind of payload might come to nifi

Comment: The current JSON values are wrong while the previous ones were right.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are following is making it a little more complex :

```
I am not able to understand the Input Json as it is not proper but I guess this solution will help in resolving your issue :

Input : 

    {
  "quantity": {
    "target": {
      "amount": "xxxxx",
      "baseUoM": "xxxxx",
      "ISOBaseUoM": "xxxxx"
    }
  },
  "dates": {
    "plannedFinishDate": "xxxxx",
    "plannedStartDate": "xxxxx",
    "actualFinishDate": "xxxxx"
  },
  "billOfMaterials": "xxxxx",
  "deletionIndicator": "",
  "routingNumber": "xxxxx",
  "mainWorkCenter": "xxxxx",
  "orderRecipe": "xxxxx",
  "item": {
    "number": "xxxxx",
    "product": {
      "id": "xxxxx",
      "number": "xxxxx",
      "description": "xxxxx",
      "baseUoM": "xxxxx",
      "ISOBaseUoM": "xxxxx"
    },
    "goodsReceipt": {
      "amount": "xxxxx",
      "baseUoM": "xxxxx",
      "ISOBaseUoM": "xxxxx"
    },
    "storageLocation": {
      "code": "xxxxx",
      "description": "xxxxx"
    }
  },
  "reservation": {
    "id": "xxxxx",
    "number": "xxxxx"
  },
  "materialMovements": [
    {
      "id": "xxxxx",
      "number": "xxxxx",
      "postingDate": "xxxxx",
      "items": [
        {
          "number": "xxxxx"
        },
        {
          "id": "xxxxx"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "sourceSystem": "NA"
}

Jolt Spec :

    [
          {
            "operation": "shift",
            "spec": {
              "quantity": {
                "target": {
                  "*": "[#4].&"
                }
              },
              "dates": {
                "*": "[#3].&"
              },
              "billOfMaterials": "[#2].&",
              "deletionIndicator": "[#2].&",
              "routingNumber": "[#2].&",
              "mainWorkCenter": "[#2].&",
              "orderRecipe": "[#2].&",
              "materialMovements": {
                "*": {
                  "id": "[&1].id",
                  "number": "[&1].number",
                  "items": {
                    "*": {
                      "number": "[&1].no"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }, 
//For Flattening Array to Single Json
{
         "operation": "shift",
         "spec": {
           "*": {
             "*": "&"
           }
         }
      }
            ]
```

Comment: Thanks Arnold, Is there any way, i can get a single flattened JSON. Right now its coming like this, items inside material movements is coming in an array after the joltspec

Comment: Hey you can use this to transform it to single flatten Json :

    {
        "operation": "shift",
         "spec": {
           "*": {
             "*": "&"
           }
         }
      }

 I will edit this in current spec.